# Adding a form field add with a mathematical question to stop bots? :(

Tags: php, forms, captcha, spam

Good day, I'm looking for assisting on this. On my PHP page, I'm looking to add a simple mathematical question (ex: 5+2) to stop the spam. Any recommendation please? Would be highly appreciated, also feel free if there's way I can improve my code.

Here is my PHP page and form fields:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <?php
            // Contact Form
            function contact_form() {
                if(isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != "")
                {
                    if(!filter_var($_POST["mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        echo "<div class='error'>The email address is not valid</div>";
                        return;
                    }

                    if($_POST["name"] == "" || $_POST["mail"] == "" || $_POST["message"] == "") {
                        echo "<div class='error'>Informations are missing</div>";
                        return;
                    }

                    $name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
                    $message = htmlentities($_POST["message"]);
                    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

                    $to      = '@hotmail.com';
                    $subject = 'Message of '.$name.'';
                    $headers = 'From: ' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                    $message_final = "Someone sent you a message \nNom : ".$name."\nCourriel : ".$_POST["mail"]."\n\n\n".$message;

                    if(mail($to, $subject, $message_final, $headers)) {
                        echo "<div class='success'>Your message was sent. Thank you!</div>";
                        return;
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='error'>There was an error. You message was not sent</div>";
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
            contact_form();
            ?>

            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Cheers

Comment: please have a look to csrf to avoid "bad request" from bot, or just google reCAPTCHA to be sure that was a human that has compiled the request

Comment: Thank you @Berto99 I tried, but with no success. I'm just trying to add a simple question in this form. :/

Comment: why "no success"? can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I actually do something just like what you've described. There are varying ways to implement this, but an easy way is use a function that generates a random math problem, hashes the answer, and inserts the hash into a hidden field. The user submits the form, and you compare the hash of the answer submitted with the hash in the hidden field. You may also want to consider using unique tokens for forms so forms can't POST to your site without getting a token first.

Comment: Thank you @InterLinked, if I just want to add a form field with a question 5+2 and if it matches the answer on the PHP which would be 7, it would be validated. Do you know how I would write it?

Comment: Of course, I followed this website tutorial (https://themehunt.com/blog/28-web-tips-and-tricks/bootstrap-tips-and-tricks/168-how-to-add-recaptcha-to-bootstrap-contact-form) and downloaded there test folder for the catchpa, but they are many folders and it seems I haven't implemented it well since there's seems to have so many folders and sub folder. 

I'm not to much good with coding so I figure just adding a question to my already existing form would be sufficient. :/

Comment: Kind thanks @InterLinked

Comment: A simple checkbox and/or hidden field will work. Heh, even Google agrees.

Comment: Thank you @FunkFortyNiner, I will see how I can implement it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually do something just like what you've described. There are varying ways to implement this, but an easy way is use a function that generates a random math problem, hashes the answer, and inserts the hash into a hidden field. The user submits the form, and you compare the hash of the answer submitted with the hash in the hidden field. You may also want to consider using unique tokens for forms so forms can't POST to your site without getting a token first.

You can try something like this:

```
function mathQuestion($lo, $hi) {
    $a = mt_rand($lo, $hi);
    $b = mt_rand($lo, $hi);
    $c = $a + $b;
    $hash = md5($c);
    $q = "$a + $b";
    return array($q, $hash);
}
function mathQuestionVerify($c, $hash) {
    return (md5($c) === $hash);
}
```

Then, in your form, something like:

```
$mathQ = mathQuestion(10, 89);
$mathText = $mathQ[0];
$mathHash = $mathQ[1];
echo "<div><label for='mathquestion'>What is $mathText?</label><input id='mathquestion' name='mathquestion'></div>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='mathanswer' value='$mathHash'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='token' value='$token'>";
```

The two fields above are the math related ones. <s>The token variable here is a CSRF token in a form I grabbed this from.</s> Actually, this is just a unique form token as I described earlier - I also use CSRF tokens when users are logged in.

In the example above, when the form loads, we add two numbers each of which are between 10 and 89. You can change these to whatever you want. I use a wider range of numbers for less common tasks, like password resets, since that's not something that's done frequently. For a general contact form you should probably keep these numbers small - probably under 50.

Note that ***md5 is not cryptographically secure***. Neither is **sha1**. I don't actually think `mt_rand()` is either. Just throwing this out there. I use **md5** in this case because we're not dealing with sensitive data and so a plain, fast hashing function works well for my purposes.

I don't use this mechanism as my sole method of validation, but it can certainly slow down malicious attempts. If you want to go further, you could even use a function to rewrite the numeric question into text to make it harder for bots to spam.

For your specific situation, you might try something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <?php
        // Contact Form
        function contact_form() {
            if(isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != "")
            {
                if(!isSet($_POST['mathanswer'] || !mathQuestionVerify($_POST['mathanswer'], $_POST['mathhash'])) {
                    echo "<div class='error'>Incorrect answer.</div>";
                    return;
                }
                if(!filter_var($_POST["mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    echo "<div class='error'>The email address is not valid</div>";
                    return;
                }

                if($_POST["name"] == "" || $_POST["mail"] == "" || $_POST["message"] == "") {
                    echo "<div class='error'>Informations are missing</div>";
                    return;
                }

                $name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
                $message = htmlentities($_POST["message"]);
                $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

                $to      = '@hotmail.com';
                $subject = 'Message of '.$name.'';
                $headers = 'From: ' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                $message_final = "Someone sent you a message \nNom : ".$name."\nCourriel : ".$_POST["mail"]."\n\n\n".$message;

                if(mail($to, $subject, $message_final, $headers)) {
                    echo "<div class='success'>Your message was sent. Thank you!</div>";
                    return;
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='error'>There was an error. You message was not sent</div>";
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
        contact_form();
        ?>

        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
            </div>
<?php
$mathQ = mathQuestion(5, 15); # ask user to add 2 random numbers between 5 & 15
$mathText = $mathQ[0];
$mathHash = $mathQ[1];
echo "<div><label for='mathquestion'>What is $mathText?</label><input id='mathquestion' name='mathquestion'></div>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='mathanswer' value='$mathHash'>";
?>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you @interLinked you rock! :) It's actually more than my programming knowledge... When adding the "$mathQ = mathQuestion(10, 89);
$mathText = $mathQ[0];
$mathHash = $mathQ[1];" in my form it becomes grey, not sure if I should put it in a php function. Would you have a simple add like a question 5+2 in the format I posted? This would be perfect.

Comment: That code is PHP code - not HTML - not sure if that's what you're asking? Not sure what you mean by "form becomes gray". I would *not* recommend doing just 5+2 every time - that won't really improve the security of your form at all. You should at least use small, pseudorandom numbers. If that's what you want to do, you can simply have a static form field for that and check if `$_POST['answer'] === 7` on submit.

Comment: Oh wow! Again that you so much @InterLinked you answered my question! I appreciate it so much, very helpful! <3

Comment: I appreciate all the assistance given! Oh btw in my editor it says it has an error with this line when I put the code in "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mathQuestion() in /home/contact.php:154 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/contact.php on line 154"

Comment: No problem - if this helps, please consider accepting or upvoting the answer so others can find it. The error you received indicates it can't find the file. You'll also need to copy and paste the functions I provided to you earlier in the answer into the same PHP file, or include the file they're in.